# Spring boot test cannot be executed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, junit

Ive been trying to initialize SpringBootTest on very simple rest spring boot application written in Kotlin. It looks like this so far.

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = [MySpringApp::class])
class MySpringAppTests {

    @Test
    fun funny() {
        assertThat(1 + 2).isEqualTo(3)
    }
}
```

And my springboot app

```
@SpringBootApplication
class MySpringApp

fun main() {
    runApplication<MySpringApp>()
}
```

So I don't even inject anything, yet I get this error I cannot resolve.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7
```

All I found on internet was to update gradle to newest version. It was working on latest gradle 7.1 all along and java 16. I tried to downgrade gradle to version 6 and java to v11, but it didn't help at all.

Comment: Problem dissapears when I remove @SpringBootTest annotation, but then I wont be able to inject anything

Answer (score 0):

So it ultimately was a problem with java version, but I had to change it for Gradle directly. So in Intellij go to:

**Settings -> Build, execution Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle**

Changing gradle JVM version to 11 worked for me